# Azure HDInsight - CVE-2021-44228 Apache Log4j 2

Tags: azure, azure-hdinsight

I don't see any guidance from Microsoft around HDInsight components which are using log4j for logging, on checking I am seeing the versions impacted by this on our HDInsight clusters. Is there any guidance around when the nodes in HDInsight will be patched?

https://msrc-blog.microsoft.com/2021/12/11/microsofts-response-to-cve-2021-44228-apache-log4j2/

Answer (score 0):

HDInsight Engineering team has built a patch and is currently applying it to all clouds. Public cloud patching is already complete. No customer action is needed at this time.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is a useful edit. Do you have a source for this claim? That would make it even better.

Comment: Microsoft advisory has been updated to reflect the same https://msrc-blog.microsoft.com/2021/12/11/microsofts-response-to-cve-2021-44228-apache-log4j2/